# How can I replace two double quotes with one double quotes using Regex without capturing occurrences of one double quote?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to do a replace on a `JSON` string. Something like this:

```
'{"val1":"1","val2":"2"","val3":"","val4":""}'
```

Looking at the value tied to key `"val2"`, I'm getting two double quotes together `" 2 " "`, but I can't fix that because that's how I get the `JSON`, I'm trying to replace those occurrences with 1 double quote: from `"2""` to `"2"`

I'm doing `replace()` but I can't find the right regex to do it. I have tried this:

```
replace(/""/g, '"')
```

If I do this it will replace `"val3"` and `"val4"` too.

This one doesn't work:

```
replace(/[^:]+"";/g, '"')
```

I'm trying to accomplish `replace(REGEX_HERE)`:
From `"SomeCharactersHere""` to `"SomeCharactersHere"`

Comment: Write your own custom JSON parser that ignores improper double quotes :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```js
var s = '{"val1":"1","val2":"2"","val3":"","val4":""}';
s = s.replace(/([^:])\"\"/g, '$1\"')
console.log(s);
```

This matches some non-colon character followed by a set of double-double-quotes and replaces it with the originally found non-colon character along with a single-double-quotes.

Per a suggestion by ctwheels:

```js
var s = '{"val1":"1","val2":"2"","val3":"","val4":""}';
s = s.replace(/([^:]")"+/g, '$1')
console.log(s);
```

As mentioned, it will capture the possibility of more than one extraneous double-quote and simplifies the replacement to just `$1`. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest using `([^:]")"+` instead. It captures possibility of more than 2 `"` in sequence and you only need to replace with `$1`

Answer (score 0):

I would add the comma in the match part.

```
'{"val1":"1","val2":"2"","val3":"","val4":""}'.replace(/"",/g, '\",');
```

I would also try to figure out why I'm getting badly formatted json :-)

Better yet:

```
'{"val1":"1","val2":"2"","val3":"","val4":""}'.replace(/"\([^"]+\)""/g, '"\1"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```js
const str = '{"val1":"1","val2":"2"","val3":"","val4":""}';
const cleaned = str.replace(/(\"+([^",]*)\"+)/g, (match,quotes,val) => `"${val}"`);
console.log(cleaned);
console.log(JSON.parse(cleaned));
```

Basically, it'll match each block of quotes (including extra quotes), then rewrite it to have only one pair of quotes.

Do note: it won't work if your values have commas. That's a limitation to this particular approach. If you need commas in the value, you could use this alternate regex:

```
/(\"([^"]*)\"+)/g
```

That one will work for commas, but won't work if you have a double-quote at the start of the string. You'd have to move the `+` in that case to the first one instead.